# What is the controller scheme?

Tags: controllers, ps4, inside

I'm interested in playing *Inside* on my PS4. We only have one television so I'd like to play remotely on my PS Vita, but only if the L3/R3 buttons aren't used as they are almost impossible to trigger. **What PS4 buttons are used for *Inside*?**

Comment: In the PS4 settings you can remap all controller buttons if you want to have the action on a different button. I don't know if that also works with remote play though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L3 and R3 are not used in the game.

The screen shot below is the controls page from the in game options menu, taken on my PS4.

[image: Inside controls screen shot]

The controls are simple:

- Left analogue Stick to move
- <kbd>**X**</kbd>  to jump
- <kbd>**☐**</kbd>  to grab / interact

Comment: Strange, on my controller, the left button is square, not circle! :)